# Converting AWK to Perl

Tags: perl, awk

I'm having trouble figuring how to convert this simple AWK command to Perl

```
awk -F: '{if($3 > 999 && $3 < 30000){ print $1}}' /etc/passwd
```

Thoughts?

Comment: 1. What does it do? Don't expect the people able that can help you with your Perl problem to know `awk`. 2. Which of things it does are you having a problem implementing in Perl?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html

Comment: Having the headline of the question, what about `mv /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/awk` ?:D

Comment: When you literally translate the French term of endearment `mon chou` to English you get `my cabbage` which would be an insult. Similarly if you literally translate that awk statement to perl you may get something that you would never write in perl (actually you would never even write that in idiomatic awk to begin with). So are you looking for a literal translation or an idiomatic one? Why? Post sample input and expected output either way.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl        

use strict;
use warnings;

while (1) {
   my ($user, $uid) = ( getpwent() )[0,2]
      or last;

   print("$user\n")
      if $uid >= 1_000 && $uid < 30_000;
}

endpwent();
```

Answer (score 2):

The literal equivalent is like this

```
perl -aF: -ne'print "$F[0]\n" if $F[2] > 999 and $F[2] < 30_000' /etc/passwd
```